# Make Docker available inside the Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers, devops

I need to make docker available inside the Jenkins container. I saw the below command in a blogpost.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d -v /home/user1/jenkins-pv:/var/jenkins_home -v 
 var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins
```

However, every time I execute docker command inside the container, I get the below output of snap command. Can someone help me to resolve this?

```
jenkins@9946a785822d:/$ docker
The snap command lets you install, configure, refresh and remove snaps.
Snaps are packages that work across many different Linux distributions,
enabling secure delivery and operation of the latest apps and utilities.

Usage: snap <command> [<options>...]

Commonly used commands can be classified as follows:

         Basics: find, info, install, remove, list
        ...more: refresh, revert, switch, disable, enable, create-cohort
        History: changes, tasks, abort, watch
        Daemons: services, start, stop, restart, logs
    Permissions: connections, interface, connect, disconnect
  Configuration: get, set, unset, wait
    App Aliases: alias, aliases, unalias, prefer
        Account: login, logout, whoami
      Snapshots: saved, save, check-snapshot, restore, forget
         Device: model, reboot, recovery
      ... Other: warnings, okay, known, ack, version
    Development: download, pack, run, try

For more information about a command, run 'snap help <command>'.
For a short summary of all commands, run 'snap help --all'.
```

type command output

```
user1@vm-1:~$ type docker
docker is /snap/bin/docker
```

Comment: What does `type docker` outputs?

Comment: You can get inside your container using exec and then install docker in it. Did you try this?

Comment: user1@vm-1:~$ type docker
docker is /snap/bin/docker